# How to add new line after each column to output of api mvc controller code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I want to add new line after each column for the api output in mvc controller , This is the controller code :

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetUsers(string username, string password, int branchid)
        {
            using (DB entities = new DB())
            {
                var entityuser = entities.Users_web.Where(user => user.user_name.Equals(username, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && user.user_password == password && user.branch_id == branchid).ToList();

                Userloginstatus userlogin = new Userloginstatus
                {
                    Success = true,
                    users = entityuser,
                    Message = "User Name Found"

                };

                FalseStatus falsestat = new FalseStatus
                {
                    Success = false,
                    Message = "User Name or Password incorrect"
                };

                if (entityuser.Any())
                {
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, userlogin);
                    
                }
                else
                {
                     return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound,falsestat);
                   
                }
            }
  

        }
```

the output now if user found and success appear all data in one row :

```
{"Success":true,"users":[{"user_id":3924,"user_fullname":"suaad alhaijili ","user_phone":"050089 ","user_address":"\r\n","user_email":"","user_code":"1","date_added":"2020-12-13T19:54:02.657","user_kind_id":3,"user_name":"123456789","user_password":"123456","group_id":1,"user_logo":null,"custid":0,"patient_no":30,"branch_id":2}],"Message":"User Name Found"}
```

but I need the output to be like this and add new line after each column :

```
{"Success":true,
"users":[{
         "user_id":3924,
         "user_fullname":"suaad  ",
          "user_phone":"050089 ",
          "user_address":"\r\n",
          "user_email":"", 
          "user_code":"1", 
          "date_added":"2020-12-13T19:54:02.657",
          "user_kind_id":3,
          "user_name":"123456789",
          "user_password":"123456",
          "group_id":1,
           "user_logo":null,
           "custid":0,
           "patient_no":30,
            "branch_id":2
        }],
"Message":"User Name Found"}
```

UPDATE:

I added the last line to file global.asax as mentioned in the solution but still same not formatted as needed still same row all data in one row :

```
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
            {
                protected void Application_Start()
                {
                    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
                    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
                    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
                    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
                    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
                    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
      
    
                    }
            }
```

also this is the webapiconfig file

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
           
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
            var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
            config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
            

                 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "ActionRoute",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
               // defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
            // config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
        }
    }
```

How can I do that and add new line after each column

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the JSON formatter to "Indented".  You seem to indicate that you are not using .Net Core, so this answer is for WebApi on .Net Framework.

Add this line to the Application_Start method in your global.asax:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
```

Comment: I added the line but got error Member 'Formatting.Indented' cannot be accessed with an instance reference qualify it with a type , i added global.asax file to question thank you

Answer (score 0):

Its working after work around first update the webapiconfig file like this remove extra lines and keep:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
                       
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "ActionRoute",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
              
            );

            config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
          
        }
```

and add this line to file Global.asax :

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
```